# Cross browser issues CSS - div totally different location on Chrome

Tags: css

My website is working great on most browsers but for some reason Chrome is showing my navigation items outside of the header bar. I'm not sure which part of my CSS is at fault here and why it is being interpreted differently between browsers. Help would be appreciated. You need to look at it with screen size of 1100px or higher to see what I mean - lower than that and it turns into responsive navigation button.

Here's a link to show you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8LIn.jpg

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
 line-height: 1.428;
    background-color:#956396;
 }
.wrap {
   width: 90%;
   max-width: 71.5em;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0.625em 0.625em;
}
#header {
 background: #442869; 
 padding-top: 1em;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
 min-height: 6em;
}
#mobile-navigation-btn {
 display: none;
 float: right;

}
#navigation {
 display: block;
 float: right;
}

#navigation ul {

 list-style: none;

}

#navigation li {

 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 padding-right: 2em;
 padding-top: 1em;
 padding-bottom: 1em;

}
#navigation li:last-child {
padding-right: 0em;
}
#navigation li a {
 color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none; 
}

.show-menu {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #956396;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 10px;
border: 1px black solid;
     border-radius: 10px;


}

.show-menu:hover {
 background: #9b729b;
}

#extra {
 background: #ffffff; 
 padding-top: 1em;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
 min-height: 2em;
 color: white;

}

#extra2 {
 background: #956396; 
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #navigation{
    display: block;

    
}


#hamburger {
display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
top: 5px;

}

.icon-bar {
display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 920px) {
#mobile-navigation-btn {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
top: 20px;
 }
 
#navigation {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color:#956396;
    margin-top: 28px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;

}

 /*Create vertical spacing*/
 #navigation li {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
 }
 /*Make dropdown links vertical*/
#navigation ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
   margin:0;
  padding:0;

}

 /*Make all menu links full width*/
 #navigation ul li, li a {
  width: 100%;

 }
#extra {
clear: both;
}



}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
    // Picture element HTML5 shiv
    document.createElement( "picture" );
  </script>
  <script src="picturefill.min.js" async></script>
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <div class="wrap">
  
 <picture>
  <source srcset="seiri-logo-regular.png" media="(min-width: 1100px)">
  <img srcset="seiri-logo-small.png" alt="…">
</picture>

<div id="mobile-navigation-btn">
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">
  <div id="hamburger">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </div> Menu
            </label>
 
 </div>

 <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
 <div id="navigation">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Customer Research</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Business Improvement</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div> 
   

  
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
      <div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Looks fine for me in Chrome 46

Comment: Firefox 38, Chrome 43 & 44, IE 11 all look the same. Check your zoom on each browser.

Comment: Looks fine for me too in crome 44.

Comment: That's strange. I'm seeing this. http://imgur.com/m5sVBww  And that's at 100%. Although when I refresh it does revert to what I should be. It's just when I first open it. Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: Could it be because I have two "float: right" elements? Whilst only one div shows on mobile version and the other only shows on full version, it seems to be that bit of code that's causing these issues. Rather than floating the navigation right it's pushing it down to the next available space.